# PHP Header Redirect in a new window?

Tags: php, redirect

For a banner management system i use a

```
 header("Location: http://www.awebsite.com");
```

to redirect to the proper website. Is it possible to force this header script to open in a new window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href='yourbannerscript.php' target='_blank'>...</a>
```

Comment: This does not answer the initial need. Using PHP `header()` function, it's simply impossible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539011/header-location-in-new-tab

Answer (score 3):

No.  If you want a new window, you have to deliver the redirect as HTML/Javascript.

Comment: No argument.  It's all kind of gross to me once the word 'banner' comes into it.

Comment: And if I can't use js are there other options?

Comment: Obviously the best thing is if you can get a target="_blank" into the original link, like legenden says.  (It wasn't thinking you had control over that.)  If for some reason you can't push JS to the client (I assume there's a social reason for that, since it's pretty much impossible for there to be a technical reason), you're pretty much out of luck; all you could do would be to send HTML with a link and ask the user to click on it.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
echo "<script>window.open('yoursite.com');</script>";
```

Comment: You do this and every pop up blocker will block the redirect page.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nasty, and might not be want you want, but including an IFRAME tag pointing to a php file with the header redirect could be a solution. Doesn't create a new window, but creates a window-within-a-window.

```
<iframe src="/myredirectscript.php"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect to a page with a redirect metà tag like the one on the most voted answer at [Open HTML meta redirect in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852154/open-html-meta-redirect-in-new-window)

So the page you redirect your headers to will contain a metà tag with:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" />
<meta content="0; URL=javascript:window.open('http://uri.of
.your.pagewhereyouwabtoredirect/path','_parent');"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Not possible.. Instead of that you can set open new tab in form attribute **target="_blank"**

```
 <form target="_blank" method="post" action="contact-function.php">
```