# Open HTML meta redirect in new window

Tags: html

I need web page to redirect via HTML meta and open that page in a new window. How can I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Photo Gallery Redirect</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://google.com">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you ad something more on "Photo Gallery Redirect"

Comment: OMG. Why? Did some client request it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You need to use javascript on a timer to open a popup (which most likely will be blocked by some browsers as an unrequested popup window)

You are probably better off taking a different approach to your problem.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this! It is particularly useful when the refresh is being run in an iframe (such as a Facebook app canvas page), and you want the refresh to load the content to the main (parent) window.

Use the following Javascript in your meta-redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=javascript:window.open('http://google.com','_parent');">
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks!
Tested and working to make sharepoint links as .htm files :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with a meta redirect. Grab JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('http://google.com');</script>
```

Either that, or add `target="_blank"` to the originating link/form which landed in this "Photo Gallery Redirect" page.

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

or

```
<form action="http://google.com" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Not XHTML/HTML5 valid, but it works. Else you can just add `rel="ext"` and use some piece of Javascript to silently put the `target="_blank"` in anyway.

Comment: Beware of popup blockers for unrequested popup windows.

Answer (score 0):

make it without using url attribute just like this

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;https://stackoverflow.com">
```