# How to put target of link in php with this script

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirect in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950518/redirect-in-a-new-window)

Here is my script

```
header("Location: ".$links.);
```

How to put  the target to open a new blank window for this ?

I know there are other way to open new window from link with PHP. But for this i have no idea.

here is some lines of php srcipt

if ($kw_type=="1") { header("Location: ".$links.); (in this case it will send link to ajax to open it) }

if ($kw_type=="2") { echo"$word_case"; ( in this case it will send normal data to ajax) }

Comment: ?: so you want a link in your page to open content to a new page? or do you want it to open a window when the window is loaded?

Comment: I use ajax to pull data (link) from sql. Then open that link...But what i get is the link is displaying in the result div ( I want it open in the new windows...)

Comment: Here is some lines of script php
 
if ($kw_type=="1") {
 header("Location: ".$links.);  (in this case it will send link to ajax to open it)
 
 
 }
 
if ($kw_type=="2") {
  echo"$word_case";  ( in this case it will send normal data to ajax)
  
  
 }

Comment: I have found the best solution by using function split to seperate the respond text into array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to open a new window using server side scripting.

You'll need to use JavaScript for that, or a HTML link.

Comment: hmm  I have no idea. Because I use ajax to pull the data (link) from database php. And I want it to open in the new page not in the result-div...What should I do ?

Comment: Why not do it in the Ajax call? Why does it have to be a server-side redirect?

Comment: Because in my ajax it will pull 2 type of data from database:
if it get tye A, will show only normal data.
if it get type B will open the link.

That why I have no idea :S

Comment: Here is some lines of script php
 
if ($kw_type=="1") {
 header("Location: ".$links.);  (in this case it will send link to ajax to open it)
 
 
 }
 
if ($kw_type=="2") {
  echo"$word_case";  ( in this case it will send normal data to ajax)
  
  
 }

Comment: I have found the best solution by using function split to seperate the respond text into array.