# Header Location in new tab

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirect in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950518/redirect-in-a-new-window)

Please don't mind if it is foolish question,

Is it possible in php to open a window in new tab using

```
  header(Location: 'blahblah');
```

Comment: This sounds like a quick and easy test?

Comment: testing the easiest is not difficult, but testing the difficult is what difficult :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The header will simply redirect the current page, in the current window/tab.

Answer (score 15):

No it is not possible using php as php is a server side language and what you are want is a client side feature. So you will have to do it with some javascript.

You can definitely try something like this via javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">window.open('http://www.example.com');</script>
```

Comment: And that will be eaten by every popup blocker out there.