# equivalent of <a href="test" target="_blank"> in the php header() function

Tags: php

Does someone know how to have the equivalent of

```
<a href="test" target="_blank">
```

in the php header() function

I need to re direct my php page in new tab.

Comment: HTTP redirects don't interact with client windows. This can only be commanded from HTML.

Comment: That's not possible with header. Make use of JS Redirect instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Header Location in new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539011/header-location-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. PHP has no control over the browser.

The best you can do is:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.open(...);</script>';
```

But this will probably be blocked by a popup blocker.

Alternatively, if possible, you can have whatever initiated the PHP request itself be set to `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side language and cannot be used to perform client-side actions, i.e. you cannot open a new window using a [`header()`](http://php.net/header) redirect. It will always redirect the current page. If you want the link to be opened in a new tab, you will have to use JavaScript.

For example:

```
<?php
echo "<script>window.open('http://www.example.com');</script>";
?>
```

Still, this isn't guaranteed to work because the user might have popup blockers installed on their browser.