# PHP header opening in _blank

Tags: php, header, anchor

I use a header location to link another site at my site. Please, don't look after this manner, I can't do anything with it...
My code looks like this

```
if($navigateId==82) {
        header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
        header( "Location: http://newsite.com/sample-link" ); 
    }
```

I would like, if I only can open this anchor at new card (target="_blank")
Thanks for help

Comment: It's not possible... Check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539011/header-location-in-new-tab

Comment: So Is there another manner to solve my problem?

Comment: Check the answer of Rakesh for a possible direction

Comment: @RichardBernards rakesh copied the answer from your provied link only

Comment: @Veerendra I hadn't checked that yet... Well, maybe he needs some extra rep-points :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you are using server-side redirection and the target="_blank" is client-side directive to browser to open the URL in new window (or tab). So I don't think that you can arrange it using server-side coding.

BTW, I have found already this question answered - [Header Location in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539011/header-location-in-new-tab)

You can arrange needed functionality using jquery. I mean if the link which needs to be checked and opened in new window is not static html content or entered in a WYSIWYG you can check by AJAX call the id server-side and open it in new window if needed. The checkings can be done also client side but you have to supply the javascript code with the ID-s which need to be opened in new window.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not possible.  header will simply redirect the current page, in the current window.

For this you need to use js like:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('http://www.example.com');</script>
```

For more :- [Header Location in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539011/header-location-in-new-tab)

Comment: junedkazi answer copied from the link posted by RichrdBernards you should post the link in the comment if answer is already on SO

Comment: window.open will more than likely be blocked as a pop up in most browsers...