# Issue in retrieve data from sql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created register form using php. I have index.php,submit.php,functions.php and script.

Now it works fine, and i need to retrieve the data from database and display in front end.

I am new to php, and i am learning. please help me to do this.

This is my data.php:

```
    <?php 
    include ('condb.php');
    $query = mysql_query("select * from test where id='".$_GET['id']."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
    <body>
        <h3>Employee Detail</h3>
        <p>Emp Name:</p> <?php echo $row['fname'];?>
        <p>LastName:</p> <?php echo $row['lname'];?>
    </body>
<?php ?>
```

and this is action.php:

```
           <?php
include('condb.php');

extract($_POST);
$que=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id, fname, lname) VALUES ('$id', '$fname', '$lname')") or die("Error Msg!");
if($que)
{
    header('Location: data.php?id='.$id.'');
}

?>
```

index.html:

```
<body bgcolor="#2E2E2E">
        <table align="center" cellpadding="5" style="background:#A4A4A4; border-radius:4px; margin-top:40px; padding:15px;">
            <h1 style="text-align:center; color:white; margin-top:50px">Employee Registration Form</h1>
            <form method="post" action="action.php">
                <tr><td>First Name:</td><td> <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required /></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td> <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Register Me!"/></td></tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    </body>
```

and condb.php:

```
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Error!");
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: which data, you want to display

Comment: all entered input details.

Comment: after successfull input

Comment: check this link  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: You should read some tutorials on PHP/MySQL. There are a plethora of books out there. ANd don't use MySQL Functions (`mysql_*`), they're deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Instead use `mysqli` class or functions.

Comment: i know somewhat,  that is using mysql_fetch_array() function, but i am struggling where to i add,, can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have shown code for the 3 field and you can do similarly for other fields.You can make **newfile** and paste that code their.

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT fname, lname, email FROM crop';

    mysql_select_db('crop');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "First Name :{$row['fname']}  <br> ".
             "Last Name : {$row['lname']} <br> ".
             "Email Address : {$row['email']} <br> ".
             "--------------------------------<br>";
    } 
    echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: this is what i have already seen buddy, i just where to i add to my existing code..

Comment: You have done for **insert** where as my code is for **retrieval**. What exactly do you want ? Be clear ..

Comment: Just make one file **data.php** in the same folder and do some CSS.

Comment: In the same folder that you have included all that above mentioned file.

Comment: Paste that code in **submit.php** after **query** `if($result){header('Location: data.php');}` 
So that it will directly redirect you to page where all the user are **listed** .

**NOTE**:Make sure that path to `data.php` is correct.

Comment: If you have any **unique field** like `ID` then you can change your above code to this: `if($result){ 
$sql = "SELECT fname, lname, email FROM crop where id='$id'";

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql);
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "First Name :{$row['fname']}  <br> ".
             "Last Name : {$row['lname']} <br> ".
             "Email Address : {$row['email']} <br> ".
             "--------------------------------<br>";
    }
}`

Comment: `$result` is what you have declared to INSERT query.

Comment: I am really sorry. I forgot to mention.You need to add this in your **submit.php** file.Also Make sure that you have **unique field** in `where` condition.I just take **ID** for an example. You need to add your own unique field from the database.

Comment: Download 4 files [from here](http://1drv.ms/1nZnOn6).And run it in your machine.
**NOTE**:Don't forget to create database with the same name as mentioned in PHP files.

Comment: I have tested and its working perfectly fine.You just make database with name `test` and in that database create table with name `test`.
In that `test`, create 3 column with name `id(int 10)` `fname(varchar 30)` `lname(varchar 30)`.And don't forget to my accept answer. :)

Comment: yah ..tell me .. Whats the issue?

Comment: `registered.html` ?? I did not have such file.How can it be possible ??

Comment: Ok .. as you can see in the URL bar, It is not getting the ID .Have you added ID field in the URL ?

Comment: Ohh buddy !! Remove Auto_increment and then try.We are entering ID manually.So we don't need Auto_Increment.

Comment: Whats the error ? screen shot pls :)
Error means it is working somehow :)

Comment: Replace this line `$que=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id,fname, lname) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname')") or die("Error msg !");` with `$que=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (id, fname, lname) VALUES ('$id', '$fname', '$lname')") or die("Error Msg!");` .
Also remove `$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];` coz `extract($_POST)` will do the same thing for us.

Comment: `<tr><td>ID:</td><td> <input type="text" id="id" name="id" required /></td></tr>` add this line just above First Name in index.php.
Because we are retrieving data from that ID.
As you can notice that line in data.php `header('Location: data.php?id='.$id.'');`

Comment: It means you want to data.php in new tab .Is it so ?

Comment: yes,, and index page stays same and no need to add id.. i want to auto increment for id

Comment: Okay dude ..Its probably the last time I am helping you.
Download new **data.php** from [here](http://1drv.ms/1o0V0dP). Also make `id` as Auto_Increment in database.Then Try.
Its tested in me and working fine.

Comment: Its okay. Try to run that code. And also try to learn debugging .

Comment: There might be option of SAVE or Go at the end of that page.

Comment: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539011/header-location-in-new-tab)
It is not possible using the PHP.And as per our logic we can not use JS at that part ..

Comment: Yah ! Thanks !
Here is some suggestion for better PHP learning. 
First learn debugging to see where are yo making mistake and try to understand the error.That will really help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the select statement to retrieve data from the database.
After you select the data from the database, you have to fetch the data to make it usefull.

For example:

```
$queryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM crop");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult);
```

When you are going to print the result , you are going to see all the selected data from the database

```
print_r($result);
```

Comment: you can put this code into the file where you are going to show the data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
       include 'config.php';
        error_reporting(E_ERROR);
        session_start();
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
        $month=$_POST['month'];
        $day=$_POST['day'];
        $year=$_POST['year'];

        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass, phone,`sex_select`, month,day,year)  
    VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass','$phone','$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')");
    if(mysql_affected_rows()>1)
        {

        //it will redeirect you to. your any file. 
        //you can give any file name here. 
           $_SESSION['fname']=$fname;//you are adding value to the session
         $_SESSION['lanme']=$lname; //you are adding value to the session
    //Do this for rest of your value
    header('Location:Your_File_name.php');
        }



    if (!$result) {
        die(msg(0,"wrong query"));
    }
        ?>
```

In the file where you are Redirecting too. You dont have to redirect. 
if You dont want to redirect dont redirect. but understand the concept
you can acess these $_SESSION any where after start_start(); at any file

```
    session_start();

//now you have access to all those value. which you stored in $_SESSION
echo $_SESSION['fname'];
echo $_SESSION['lanme'];
//In short which ever value you store in $_SESSSION you can echo them 
//out on any page.
```

In That file

```
<?php

//lets say there is one more file you want to do 
//that 

//do the same thing 

 session_start();

 echo $_SESSION['fname'];
echo $_SESSION['lanme'];
```

Comment: within a minutes, i have to move dr, can you help me as soon as possible?

Comment: what is this,     header('Location:Your_File_name.php');

Comment: i can't understand dr, can you send zip?

Answer (score -1):

Markkh answered you but also make sure that you escape the input from $_POST otherwise you'll have SQL Injection problems.
php.net/mysql_real_escape_string