# Using target="_blank" in a php redirect. Where do i put it?

Tags: php, redirect

Good day stackoverflow. Thank you for your time.

I have this php

```
$ImageLinks['image.png'] = 'http://www.example.com/r/redirect.php';
```

which redirects to the 'redirect.php' - which is the following

```
<?php $URL="http://thetargetlinktobeopenedinnewtab.com";
header ("Location: $URL");
exit();
?>
```

How can I make this $URL open in a new tab? I've tried placing the target="_blank" all over the place.

Comment: You can't do that in a redirect, it has to be done in the original link to the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Header Location in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539011/header-location-in-new-tab)

Answer (score 2):

`target` is an HTML attribute; it has nothing to do with PHP redirects.

What you're attempting to do isn't possible. The header you're returning will redirect the user but it can't open a new tab.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to do it by adding more php or some script maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out via javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">window.open('http://www.example.com');
</script>
```

Now, you can use a javascript generator from php to convert this to PHP code.

Please note this will fail with a lot of the pop-up blockers around.