# How do I use javascript to make php's header location go to new tab?

Tags: javascript, php

header("Location: post-sent.html");

I know you can't open in new tab with PHP. How do I do it with javascript or HTML if possible?

Comment: Call `window.open()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Header Redirect in a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950518/php-header-redirect-in-a-new-window)

Comment: In Javascript you can use window.open(), Using HTML you need to add target attribute for acher tag. e.g <a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>

Answer (score 0):

if( isset($_GET['$abc'] ){

//do your code here, example:
echo 'window.open("page.php", $other_Attribute )';

}

Answer (score 0):

As asked here: [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

`window.open(url,'_blank');`

PHP is not opening anything on client. It just returns data :)