# how to redirect different pages on every click on new person?

Tags: php, html

i try to redirect on every new page when someone click on my link. i made a code but its only for one person. this is my code.

```
<?php
session_start();

$links = array('https://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java', 'https://seomagnifier.com/backlinks-maker',);

$currentLink = isset($_SESSION['link']) ? $_SESSION['link'] : 0;

if ($currentLink >= count($links)) {
  $currentLink = 0;
}

$link = $links[$currentLink];

$currentLink++;
$_SESSION['link'] = $currentLink;

header("Location: $link");
exit;
?>
```

I want my link redirect new page when click by same person or a someone new person

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Header Redirect in a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950518/php-header-redirect-in-a-new-window)

Comment: No, it is not possible. The header will simply redirect the current page, in the current window/tab.

Comment: so what i do for this

Comment: Use `javascript or <a href="" target="_blank">` instead of `header()`.

Comment: just have to change header section??

Comment: Yes, using `header()` you can never open the link in the new tab or window.

Comment: sir i want when new person click on my link they redirect on new website. above code worked but for the same person. i want every new person also

Comment: How will you distinguish between the same person and a new person?

Comment: Sir, if I count the clicks, I mean add them to the database and the link that remains on that number should be opened as per the count. Could something like this happen??

Comment: Yes you could store `$currentLink` in a database, then load, increment and save on every view of the page. You do not need a user session for that because sessions are unique per user, that is what they are for.

Comment: i stored $currentLink value in database but how to display next link according to the database value. please help